# Can we use JMS in the middle of proxy flow in mule

Tags: jms, jax-ws, activemq-classic, mule, esb

Actually we have produced JAX-WS web services, and it is working fine. But now we want to use Mule ESB's  JMS. But i'm unable to configure that.

I have tried Mule's Proxy for webservices, and it is working fine. But we are trying to put JMS in between HTTP Endpoints. But the body of the soap cannot be transferred to the other end (i.e. to our services) 
JMS Server is ActiveMQ.

Thanks in advance,

Copied the flow from comment --

```
<flow name="finalFlow1" doc:name="finalFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8888" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <jms:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        queue="servicesQueue" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
        method="POST" address="localhost:5050/MyServices" ; mimeType="text/xml"
        contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP" />
</flow>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: @Seba, we would like to integrate Mule's JMS before our soap based webservices. ie we would like to forward the soap request through Mule's JMS Queue.

Comment: It seems you want to consume messages from JMS queue and send these messages to SOAP based outbound endpoint. This is a fairly straightforward scenario. Can you update your question with the mule flow that you have written, so that we can better assist you?

Comment: Yes You are right @Seba. following is the flow
<flow name="finalFlow1" doc:name="finalFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8888" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<jms:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queue="servicesQueue" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://localhost:5050/MyServices" mimeType="text/xml" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>

Comment: If you need to consume messages from a queue in the middle of a flow, you should take a look at this: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/

Comment: @Seba This is the correct answer: you should post it as answer then :)

Comment: Done! Should have posted it as an answer in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In the flow that you posted you are consuming the message via HTTP based inbound endpoint. If you just want to consume this message from JMS and send it to another HTTP endpoint, you need to use JMS inbound

```
<flow name="finalFlow1" doc:name="finalFlow1">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        queue="servicesQueue" doc:name="JMS" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="5050" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" path="MyServices"
        mimeType="text/xml" />
</flow>
```

However, this will just send the payload as is and not going to convert it into SOAP payload. If you want to convert the message consumed from JMS to SOAP payload, you need to use CXF

```
<flow name="finalFlow1" doc:name="finalFlow1">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        queue="servicesQueue" doc:name="JMS" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]" />

    <logger message="SOAP call started" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <http:outbound-endpoint 
        mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" path="MyServices" host="localhost" port="5050">
        <cxf:proxy-client payload="body"
            enableMuleSoapHeaders="false">
            <cxf:inInterceptors>
                <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
            </cxf:inInterceptors>
            <cxf:outInterceptors>
                <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
            </cxf:outInterceptors>
        </cxf:proxy-client>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>

    <logger message="SOAP call completed" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

If you just want to kickoff the JMS consumption via HTTP you can go with what Seba suggested using  MuleRequester - https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester/blob/master/mulerequesterdemo/src/main/app/MuleRequesterDemo.xml

Comment: How can i send request from SOAP? 
To which address i need to send?

Comment: The http:outbound-endpoint is where you mention the address for sending the request to SOAP based web-service. In the example code that I shared above, it is configured to send the request to http://localhost:5050/MyServices

Comment: I would like to send request from SOAP UI  to JMS, from JMS it should be forwarded to localhost:5050/Myservices

SOAP UI --> JMS --> localhost:5050/MyServices

But my question is, in SOAP UI which URL I need to mention?

If i mention localhost:5050/MyServices, the request directly goes to myservices. But i need to use JMS Queue Service in middle.

Comment: To accomplish that write another flow which listens to HTTP address where SOAP UI will send message. Consume the message and route it JMS outbound endpoint queue="servicesQueue". The flow(name="finalFlow1" ) in my answer above will pick the message from JMS queue and process it and send it further.

Comment: If i do like that, i'm getting some other problem. While getting the message from JMS Queue, my services unable to understand the message format. Is there any way to get the original SOAP message at MyServices.

Comment: <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8888" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="servicesQueue" mimeType="text/xml" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="7070" path="AMServices" method="POST" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>

Comment: ERROR 2014-02-04 11:43:46,759 [[vbrtestmulejms].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.InputStreamRequestEntity: Attempted read from closed stream.
java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:160)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to consume messages from a queue in the middle of a flow, you should take a look at this: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module